typo3 7.6 , News 6.3.0 - processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations not working
Use case: When saving a news istance in backend I want to manipulate values before saving to database.

I include my hook in the following way in ext_localconf.php:

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][]= \Vendor\mytheme\Hooks\NewsControllerSettings::class;

In my Hooks I have write this code to Check if the Hook is Firing but it haven't .
<?php

 namespace Vendor\mytheme\Hooks;

  class NewsControllerSettings {

          public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray,\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $pObj){
              echo 'Hello world ! '; 
              exit();
          }
 }



I can't upgrade the version of typo3 or even the news, but I don't know what else to try.
I hope someone can help me. Opinions are also welcome.
Thanks in advance

Have you cleared all caches through Install tool ?

First, register the hook in the ext_localconf.php like so:
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations'][] = \Vendor\Mytheme\Hooks\DataHandlerHook::class . '->processDatamapAfterDatabaseOperations';

Second, rename your namespace, as it doesn't follow naming convention:
<?php

namespace Vendor\Mytheme\Hooks;

Third, make sure your filestructure is accurate:
<pre>
typo3conf/ext/mytheme/
├── Classes/
    └── Hooks/
        └── DataHandlerHook.php
</pre>

Fourth, fix your PHP class and give the file a descriptive name like DataHandlerHook.php:
<?php

namespace Vendor\Mytheme\Hooks;

class DataHandlerHook
{
    /**
     * Hook function that is called after database operations are performed
     *
     * @param string $status The operation status ('new' or 'update')
     * @param string $table The table name being processed
     * @param int|string $id The record's ID
     * @param array $fieldArray The data array being processed
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $dataHandler The DataHandler object
     */
    public function processDatamapAfterDatabaseOperations($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $dataHandler)
    {
      # do something
    }
}

Fifth, make sure your namespace is reflected in the extensions composer.json file:
{
  "name": "vendor/mytheme",
  "description": "Your TYPO3 extension description.",
  "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Mytheme\\": "Classes/"
    }
  }
}

Lastly, empty your caches.

I think you don't have the right signature for your method, parameter &$fieldArray, try this :
<?php

namespace Vendor\mytheme\Hooks;

class NewsControllerSettings {

  /**
   * Generate a different preview link     *
   *
   * @param string $status status
   * @param string $table table name
   * @param int $recordUid id of the record
   * @param array $fields fieldArray
   * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject parent Object
   */
  public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations(
      $status,
      $table,
      $recordUid,
      array $fields,
      \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject
  ) {
      echo 'Hello world ! '; 
      exit();
  }
}


Thanks everyone. I solved it by inserting "mytheme" in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][here] and keeping the hook unchanged.
By uninstalling and reinstalling the extension I managed to intercept the event
